# Front camera is reversed

Tags: front-camera, lg-g4

On my LG G4, the front (selfie) cam is working like a mirror: if I touch my left eye, the image will display the finger touching the eye on the left side of the picture. With the back camera, it works like a normal camera: the touched eye is on the right side.
That means also, for instance, that text is reversed when using the front cam.
Is that behaviour standard ? Is there a way to have the front cam behave like a normal cam ?

Comment: For default google camera app. theres no settign to mirror the image. So we have to use an app to do this. I searched, and many of these apps are photo editing apps, which is very huge. Atlast i found one app 
Flip Image - Image Flip (Mirror Image) :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rectfy.flip

This app just do what we need, flipping image and also its size is very less. I am using this app for mirroring my photos. Its the best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the reply [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/g4/help/mirroed-text-camera-t3129586).

> While the camera app is open and the front camera is selected,
>   tap the 'settings' icon (the geared wheel) and you'll see an icon that
>   looks like two heads in profile. They will be both facing the same
>   direction by default. Tap them so they are facing away from each
>   other. Now, while the image will still appear on the screen mirrored,
>   the resulting picture will appear normal.

[[image: Screenshot][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfEAXm.png)

Comment: This varies by phone and probably by version of either Android or the phone's OS (MIUI in my case) but probably all or most Android phones will have a similar setting accessible when using the Camera app.

Answer (score -1):

in camera setting there is an option
"save as flipped" turn it off